# NestJs TypeORM role "user" does not exist with PostgreSQL server

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, node.js-typeorm

When ever I try to start my Nestjs program using PostgreSQL server, it sends this error :
ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...
error: role "user" does not exist

```
imports: [
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  url: '::1',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '12345',
  database: 'typeorm2',
  entities: ['dist/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
}),],
```

I've tried many solutions but none actually provided a fix for my problem.
I use NodeJS LTS 14.17.1

Comment: Changed the ORM to prisma, apparently typeORM doesn't work for somereason while other ORMs works just fine.